# Difference between primary key constraint vs primary key sequence?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

What is the difference between `primary key constraint` vs `primary key sequence` when it comes to `postgres` db?

Comment: I don't believe there's anything like `primary key sequence`. Source?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev http://www.neilconway.org/docs/sequences/

Comment: Nope, nothing there about a `primary key sequence`. Please note that primary keys and sequences, although frequently used together, are unrelated features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary key constraint constrains (restricts) values in the column to being unique.

A primary key sequence defines the way new unique values for a primary key are generated.